# MIF File content automatically changes after initializing ROM with the file

Tags: vhdl

I am working on single cycle risc processor. I am using altera LPM wizard ROM 1 port for instruction memory. The ROM is initialized by mif file. The content of the file is given below

```
WIDTH=16;
DEPTH=256;

ADDRESS_RADIX=HEX;
DATA_RADIX=HEX;

CONTENT BEGIN
-- default value
[00..FF] : 00;

-- instructions

00  : 2401;  -- ADI R1, R0, x01
01  : 2802;  -- ADI R2, R0, x02
02  : 2C03;  -- ADI R3, R0, x03
03  : 3011;  -- ADI R4, R0, x11
04  : 1648;  -- ADD R5, R4, R4
05  : 1AC8;  -- ADD R6, R5, R4
06  : C0C1;  -- ST  R1, R4
07  : C151;  -- ST  R2, R5
08  : C1E1;  -- ST  R3, R6
09  : 80FF;  -- BZ  R0, -1

END;
```

After I complete the initialization process the contents of mif file automatically changes to

```
-- Clearbox generated Memory Initialization File (.mif)

WIDTH=16;
DEPTH=256;

ADDRESS_RADIX=HEX;
DATA_RADIX=HEX;

CONTENT BEGIN
000  :   FFF0;
001  :   FFF1;
002  :   FFF2;
003  :   FFF3;
004  :   FFF4;
005  :   FFF5; 
     -------------
    -------------
    0fd  :   FFFD;
0fe  :   FFFE;
0ff  :   FFFF;
END;
```

I have no idea what is happening so please help..I am just learning VHDL programming

Answer (score 0):

This is not a VHDL problem! But IMO, VHDL gives you a better answer. Replace this "LPM Wizard ROM" with a plain VHDL constant array, initialised (in VHDL) to the values you want.

```
package InstMem is

type Instruction is std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
type ProgMem_Array is array 0 to 255 of Instruction;

constant Progmem : Progmem_Array := (
   00  =>  16#2401#,  -- ADI R1, R0, x01
   01  =>  16#2802#,  -- ADI R2, R0, x02
   02  =>  16#2C03#,  -- ADI R3, R0, x03
   others => (others => 0) );

end package InstMem;
```

Persuading your assembler or a Python script to write this VHDL package is trivial...

Comment: my homework is to design risc processor by using LPM Wizard ROM 1 port as instruction memory so i can change that. I have completed other things but here i got stuck.

Comment: I tested in Quartus II 12.0 and it is working fine. In Quartus II 8.1 it was not working.